# How to attach multiple files to an email using JavaMail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The following Java code is used to attach a file to an email. I want to send **multiple** files attachments through email. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class SendMail {

    public SendMail() throws MessagingException {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String Password = "mnmnn";
        String from = "xyz@gmail.com";
        String toAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
        String filename = "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Write.txt";
        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        message.setSubject("JavaMail Attachment");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("Here's the file");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);

        try {
            Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtps");
            tr.connect(host, from, Password);
            tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
            tr.close();
        } catch (SendFailedException sfe) {
            System.out.println(sfe);
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Well, it's been a while since I've done JavaMail work, but it looks like you could just repeat this code multiple times:

```
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

For example, you could write a method to do it:

```
private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String filename)
{
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();        
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

Then from your main code, just call:

```
addAttachment(multipart, "file1.txt");
addAttachment(multipart, "file2.txt");
```

etc

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It only adds the Last file attached (in this case, email only has file2.txt)

Comment: instead of calling separate method we can iterate it by passing parameters.

Comment: @Deva: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all. Iterate over what, and pass which parameters to what? Note that the OP doesn't have a collection to iterate over - they just want to add multiple separate attachments.

Comment: I meant, In above example you called addAttachment() 2 times. So, I just suggested that you can make multipart and file name are as array of object and Iterate it by passing index parameter like   addAttachment(multipartArray[i], fileArray[i]);

Comment: @Deva: Yes, if you already happen to *have* them in an array. There's little point in creating an array just to do that though - and I see no evidence that that's the case in the OP's source code. (And that would still be calling a separate method, so I'm not sure I understand the "instead of calling separate method" part of your comment.)

Answer (score 10):

### UPDATE (March 2020)

With the latest [**JavaMail™ API**](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) (*version 1.6* at the moment, [JSR 919](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=919)), things are much simpler:

- [`void attachFile(File file)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-)
- [`void attachFile(File file, String contentType, String encoding)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [`void attachFile(String file)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-)
- [`void attachFile(String file, String contentType, String encoding)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

---

#### Useful reading

Here is a nice and to the point tutorial with the complete example:

- [*JavaMail - How to send e-mail with attachments*](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java)

Comment: Yes, but how does it allow us to send more than one file?

Answer (score 6):

```
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setContent(body,"text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);

        if(filename!=null)
        {
            MimeBodyPart mbp2 = null;
            FileDataSource fds =null;
            for(int counter=0;counter<filename.length;counter++)
            {
                mbp2 = null;
                fds =null;
                mbp2=new MimeBodyPart();
                fds = new FileDataSource(filename[counter]);
                mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());
                mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
            }
        }
        msg.setContent(mp);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: You should always give an explanaiton about the code you submit

Answer (score 3):

just add another block with  using the filename of the second file you want to attach and insert it before the message.setContent(multipart) command

```
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have Array list al which has the list of attachments you need to mail and use the below given code

```
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(al.get(i));

                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource((String)al.get(i));

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName((String)al.get(i));
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                message.setContent(multipart);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File(filepath);
File[] attachments = f.listFiles();
// Part two is attachment
for( int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++ ) {
    if (attachments[i].isFile() && attachments[i].getName().startsWith("error"))  {
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource fileDataSource =new FileDataSource(attachments[i]);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachments[i].getName());
        messageBodyPart.setContentID("<ARTHOS>");
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (String fileName: files) {
            MimeBodyPart messageAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageAttachmentPart.attachFile(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageAttachmentPart);
        }
```

You have to make sure that you are creating a new mimeBodyPart for each attachment. The object is being passed by reference so if you only do :

```
 MimeBodyPart messageAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  
 for (String fileName: files) {
            messageAttachmentPart.attachFile(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageAttachmentPart);
        }
```

it will attach the same file X number of times

@informatik01 posted an answer above with the link to the documentation where there is an example of this

Answer (score 1):

Just add more files to the `multipart`.

Answer (score 1):

This is woking 100% with Spring 4+. You will have to enable less secure option on your gmail account. Also you will need the apache commons package:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@GetMapping("/some-mapping")
public void mailMethod(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFile, @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFile2) {

    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", false);

    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    javaMailSenderImpl.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(465);
    javaMailSenderImpl.setProtocol("smtp");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername("*********@gmail.com");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword("*******");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    List<CommonsMultipartFile> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    attachments.add(attachFile);
    attachments.add(attachFile2);

    javaMailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage -> {

        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        messageHelper.setTo(emailTo);
        messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        messageHelper.setText(message);

        if (!attachments.equals("")) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile file : attachments) {
                messageHelper.addAttachment(file.getOriginalFilename(), file);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        for (int alen = 0; attlen < attachments.length; attlen++) 
        {

            MimeBodyPart messageAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();    
            fileName = ""+ attachments[attlen];


            messageAttachment.attachFile(fileName);
            messageAttachment.setFileName(attachment);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageAttachment);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After Java Mail 1.3 attaching file more simpler,

- Just use MimeBodyPart methods to attach file directly or from a filepath.

  ```
  MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

  //messageBodyPart.attachFile(String filePath);
  messageBodyPart.attachFile(File file);

  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read the file name from array

```
 MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart =  new MimeBodyPart();      
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     for(int i = 0 ; i < FilePath.length ; i++){
          info("Attching the file + "+ FilePath[i]);
          messageBodyPart.attachFile(FilePath[i]);
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);                       
     }         
 message.setContent(multipart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have a better alternative for sending Multiple files in a single mail off course. Mutipart class allows us to attain this feature quite easily. If you may not have any info about it then read it from here : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Multipart.html

The Multipart class provides us two same-name methods with different parameters off course, i.e. addBodyPart(BodyPart part) and addBodyPart(BodyPart part, int index). For 1 single file we may use the first method and for mutiple files we may use the second method (which takes two parameters).

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));

            for (String email : toEmails) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(email));
                }

                message.setSubject(subject);
                BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                messageBodyPart1.setText(typedMessage);

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1, i);
                i = i + 1;

                for (String filename : attachedFiles) {
                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();


                    messageBodyPart2.attachFile(filename);

                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2, i);
                    i = i + 1;
                }

                message.setContent(multipart);
                Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working for me:

```
List<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

attachments.add("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/file1.txt");
attachments.add("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/file2.txt");
attachments.add("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/file3.txt");
attachments.add("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/file4.txt");
attachments.add("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/file5.txt");

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

if (attachments !=null && !attachments.isEmpty() ) {
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = null;
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            for(String attachment : attachments) {
                attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                attachmentPart.attachFile(new File(attachment));
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
            }
            multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
            msg.setContent(multipart);
}
Transport.send(msg);
```