# Java. Creating Microsoft Outlook email from Java

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm creating Java application which will be opening outlook email with already entered "To", "CC", "Subject", "Attachment" fields. But there is a condition: an application must have an ability for adding more than one attachment.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you post what code you have tried so far, and any compiler errors? Can you explain where the issue you are having is, and what specifically you need help with?

Comment: Similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177616/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-an-email-using-javamail

Comment: Use .NET on the client with Outlook.  The native integration is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [j-Exchange](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/) and [SyncEx](http://www.syncex.com/api/j2ee-java-api-exchange-domino.html).