# Java send email with file in attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i want to send a file in attachment using java.
I have two classes, one where the file location is specified and the second class is used as utility class to send the email
So when i execute the first class it does not send the email.

First class:

```java
public class SendFile {
    private static String[] args;

    public static void sendEmail(File filetosend) throws IOException, Exception{

    //public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final String username = "email0@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email0@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("email0@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Attach file Test from Netbeans");
        message.setText("PFA");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        //String filetosend = ("c:\\file.txt");

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filetosend);
        System.out.println("The filetosend is ="+filetosend);

        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        System.out.println("The source is ="+source);

        messageBodyPart.attachFile(filetosend);
        System.out.println("The file name is ="+messageBodyPart.getFileName());

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        System.out.println("The message body part is ="+messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        System.out.println("The message multi part is ="+multipart);


        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("The message is ="+message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And the second class:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    }
    File file;
    public void Test() throws IOException, Exception{ 
        System.out.println("Sending the file...");
        File filetosend = new File("c:\\file.txt");
        SendFile.sendEmail(filetosend);
    }
}
```

There is no error but the file is not sent.
Any help please, thank you

Comment: I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java

Comment: The problem is not to send the file. I want to get file fron the other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong. If you copied it from somewhere, the original is wrong too, or you copied it wrong.  This is what you want:

```
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email0@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("email0@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("Attach file Test from Netbeans");

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText("PFA");

    attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    System.out.println("The filetosend is ="+filetosend);
    System.out.println("The source is ="+source);

    attachmentBodyPart.attachFile(filetosend);
    System.out.println("The file name is ="+attachmentBodyPart.getFileName());

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);
    System.out.println("The message multi part is ="+multipart);

    System.out.println("Sending");

    Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  In fact, I use almost the exact same code to send messages with attachments.  You should probably look at whether or not you need to add authentication to the Transport and connect using the host, port, auth id, and auth pass.  Also, check for any firewalls blocking messages with attachments (incredibly common issue).

If you look at this post [Stack Overflow post on sending multiple attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177616/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-an-email-using-javamail?rq=1)

You will see that nearly the same thing is done, and it gives an example on how to send the message with authentication.

Comment: It s working when the file to be sent is specified in the second class but my problem is how to get the file from the first class.

Comment: Whay do you mean by getting the file in first class?

Comment: The SendFile class is used as utility class and the Test class is used to send the file by calling method from SendFile class.

Comment: I removed the first bracket of Test class, now it sends the email without the file.