# How to send mail with multiple attachments in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have here can send mail with multiple attachment:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

// creates body part for the message
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

//set message body
BodyPart msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
msgBodyPart.setText(body);
multipart.addBodyPart(msgBodyPart);
msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

//attach file
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachFile);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachFile);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

//attach file 2
source = new FileDataSource(attachFile2);
BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart2.setFileName(attachFile2);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

try {
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

      // To get the array of addresses
    for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
} catch (MessagingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

message.setSubject(subject);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

But the problem is how can I add multiple attachments? I don't know if i can declare many variable or put it on array. The code can only include 2 attachments what if 5 or any in every send of the email.

Comment: Here's a whacked out idea.  Create a method called something like `attach`, which takes a `File` and a `Multipart` as parameters.  Call it as many times as you like and see what happens :)

Comment: Do you know how Java works? (Specifically, how variables, objects and arrays work). If you do, it should be easy to see how to attach an array of files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a simple method called, something like, `attachFile`, which takes a `File`, `Multipart` and `MimeBodyPart` as parameters...

```
public void attachFile(File file, Multipart multipart, MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart) {
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);    
}
```

Call it as often as you need

```
File attachFiles[] = ...

if (attachFiles > 0) {
    //attach file
    attachFile(attachFiles[0], multipart, messageBodyPart);
    if (attachFiles > 1) {
        for (int index = 1; index < attachFiles.length; index++) {
            attachFile(attachFiles[0], multipart, new MimeBodyPart());
        }
    }
}
```

as an example

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this post. I tried to apply this to attach a couple of files to a single email. I used the same attachFile method you posted except I took the first argument as a `String filename` instead of `File file`. I tried to attach bothe the files using `attachFile("extract_emails.csv",multipart,messageBodyPart);
attachFile("Compare.txt",multipart,messageBodyPart);` there were no errors but I see that the compare.txt has been attached twice to the mail and extract_emails hasn't been attached at all. Not sure where I am going wrong. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu add a line of code "messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();" directly before the method call setDataHandler, that will fix this

Answer (score 3):

Using Java Mail 1.4 and above makes attaching file more simpler,

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
```

`messageBodyPart.attachFile(String filePath)`

```
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at answer given here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177640/772590

Step 1
  Create a Datasource

```
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Step 2 create method to add attachment

```
private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String filename)
{
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();        
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

Step 3 call above method to add attachment

```
addAttachment(multipart, "file1.txt");
addAttachment(multipart, "file2.txt");
```