# Working code that sends only one attachment

Tags: android

I have working code to send only one Attachment, but I want to send multiple attachments, please let me how if I can send multiple attachments with this code.

```
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  }
```

Comment: seems no effort !! can you plz provide some explanation about ur issue ? any error logs etc . @Awesh

Comment: As i am new to Android, I wanted to send multiple attachments, and the code above is for single attachment. If it os possible Please suggest me what i should have to do for that?,

Comment: not an issue . plz refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177616/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-an-email-using-javamail . except the answer if it will use full to you.

Comment: Thank You For The Link... It Will Help Me.. Thanx alot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can alternatively write code like this ,

```
Multipart _multipart = new MimeMultipart("test");
for (String str : attachment_List) {
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(str);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
_msg.setContent(_multipart);
Transport.send(_msg);
```